# Teradata TRANSLATE_CHK is returning 0 for non-unicode characters also

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Im trying to find the non Unicode characters for which Im using below approach,

```
SELECT TRANSLATE_CHK('我希望利用这个时间制作可' USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN);
select TRANSLATE_CHK('hyÃƒÂ¶dyt' USING UNICODE_TO_LATIN);
```

This should a non zero value as per documentation. But it is returning 0. Kindly advise. Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me. Seems you didn't set your session character set to Unicode and it defaults to ASCII :-)

Comment: Im using Teradata SQL assistance and im setting the session character set to UNICODE by this - .SET SESSION CHARSET 'UNICODE'. Is this correct?

Comment: `.SET SESSION CHARSET 'UNICODE'` is a BTEQ command which is silently ignored by SQL Assistant. Change it in your connection properties.